# Varnish stoped working and dies after start OK

Tags: linux, varnish

## EDIT 11/03/2018

I ran:

> varnishd -f  /etc/sysconfig/varnish

I got:

> Unterminated string at (input Line 96 Pos 13) DAEMON_OPTS="-a
>   ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
>   ------------###################################################### Running 
>   VCC-compiler failed, exit 1 VCL compilation failed

My /etc/sysconfig/varnish file look like this:

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variable $DAEMON_OPTS to be set from this
# shell script fragment.
#

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Locked shared memory (for ulimit -l)
# Default log size is 82MB + header
MEMLOCK=82000

# Maximum size of corefile (for ulimit -c). Default in Fedora is 0
# DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT="unlimited"

# Set this to 1 to make init script reload try to switch vcl without restart.
# To make this work, you need to set the following variables
# explicit: VARNISH_VCL_CONF, VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS,
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT, VARNISH_SECRET_FILE, or in short,
# use Alternative 3, Advanced configuration, below
RELOAD_VCL=1

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a fixed-size cache file.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#             -T localhost:6082 \
#             -b localhost:8080 \
#             -u varnish -g varnish \
#             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a
# fixed-size cache file.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#             -T localhost:6082 \
#             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
#             -u varnish -g varnish \
#             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 3, Advanced configuration
#
# See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# # Default address and port to bind to
# # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify
# # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
#
# # Telnet admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
#
# # Shared secret file for admin interface
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
#
# # The minimum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=1
#
# # The Maximum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
#
# # Idle timeout for worker threads
VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120
#
# # Cache file location
VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin
#
# # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,
# # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.
VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G
#
# # Backend storage specification
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
#
# # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
VARNISH_TTL=120
#
# # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make
# # sure you update this section, too.
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
             -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
             -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
             -w ${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS},${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS},${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
             -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
#


## Alternative 4, Do It Yourself. See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

## ORIGINAL

I run varnish whit drupal, on centos. It worked just file, when suddenly it stopped working. On :

> service varnish start

I get:

> Starting varnish HTTP accelerator: [ OK ]

But when I check status I get :

> varnishd dead but pid file exists

The logs are empty. I get no errors, and:

> varnishncsa (pid 2205) is running...

I tried :

> varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl

And got:

> storage_file: filename: ./varnish.RvBKcH size 33193 MB.
>   Using old SHMFILE

I couldn't find anything on that.
I hope someone can help me. I couldn't find anything on this issue.

This is my deaflt.vcl:

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
#  backend default {   .host = "mydomain.com";   .port = "port_num";   .connect_timeout = 3600s;   .first_byte_timeout = 3600s;   .between_bytes_timeout = 3600s; }

# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
#   sub vcl_recv {

      # Add a unique header containing the client address
        remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
        set    req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

      # set the custom header
      if (req.http.Cookie ~ "ABtesting=B") {
        set req.http.X-ABtesting = "B";
      } else {
        set req.http.X-ABtesting = "A";
      }

    # do this only once per request
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
      # normalize Accept-Encoding to reduce vary
      if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE 6") {
          unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
          set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
          set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
          unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
      }
    }

    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(Mobile|Android|iPhone|iPad)") {
      set req.http.User-Agent = "mobile";
    } else {
      set req.http.User-Agent = "desktop";
    }


     if (req.request != "GET" &&
       req.request != "HEAD" &&
       req.request != "PUT" &&
       req.request != "POST" &&
       req.request != "TRACE" &&
       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
       req.request != "DELETE") {
         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
         return (pipe);
     }
     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
         return (pass);
     }
    // Remove has_js and Google Analytics __* cookies.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
    // Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
     if (req.http.Authorization /*|| req.http.Cookie*/) {
         /* Not cacheable by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     return (lookup);  }

# 
# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_pass {
#     return (pass);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hash {
#     set req.hash += req.url;
#     if (req.http.host) {
#         set req.hash += req.http.host;
#     } else {
#         set req.hash += server.ip;
#     }
#     return (hash);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     if (!obj.cacheable) {
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
#   sub vcl_fetch {
            if (beresp.ttl > 0s) {
            /* Remove Expires from backend, it's not long enough */
            unset beresp.http.expires;

            /* Set the clients TTL on this object */
            set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age=900";

            /* Set how long Varnish will keep it */
            set beresp.ttl = 1w;

            /* marker for vcl_deliver to reset Age: */
            set beresp.http.magicmarker = "1";
            }

       # vary on the custom header
      if (beresp.http.Vary) {
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary ", X-ABtesting";
      } else {
        set beresp.http.Vary = "X-ABtesting";
      }
     if (!beresp.cacheable) {
         return (pass);
     }
     if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
         return (pass);
     }
     return (deliver);  }



#   sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.Vary) {
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "X-ABtesting", "Cookie");
    }
     if (resp.http.magicmarker) {
        /* Remove the magic marker */
        unset resp.http.magicmarker;

        /* By definition we have a fresh object */
        set resp.http.age = "0";
    }


     return (deliver);  }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} obj.status " " obj.response {"</h1>
#     <p>"} obj.response {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} req.xid {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it appears that somewhere or another you have that `DAEMON_OPTS...` line in one of your VCL files. Perhaps you have another one getting included rather than `default.vcl`. Just look for the string that is being reported in any of your files.